# When I update my machine I get 'Release does not have a Release file' error

Tags: command-line, updates, linux-headers

When I update my machine I get the following error message.

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
```

How can I update my machine?

Comment: That PPA is discontinued, it doesn't have any files.

Comment: how to fix this?

Comment: There is no fix, just remove the PPA.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 20.10?  Groovy Gorilla has not been officially released yet, so the PPA won't have a release file yet.  Also, Ubuntu 20.10 is not supported and is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the ppa from your machine...

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo rm webupd8*
```

Then update your sources.

```
sudo apt update
```

Note, since you will not be able to update Java, you may want to uninstall the outdated package from this PPA.

```
sudo apt autoremove purge oracle-java8-installer
```